# awk split into random subsets

Tags: csv, random, awk

I have a CSV file with 500k rows that I need to split into two sets, 400k and 100k each. However, I can't do something like `awk 'NR < 100000' file.csv > subset1.csv`, because the rows are sorted and I need a random distribution.
How can I randomize the two sets? As a side note, the sizes don't have to be exact,
i.e. `398111` and `101889` would be an acceptable split as well, if a perfect split is not possible in awk. Also,  I need to include the header row in both output files

Comment: you could use `shuf` to randomize the file and then use `split -l`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk. First some sample file:

```
$ seq 1 100 > file
```

then the script:

```
$ awk '{print > (rand()<=0.2?"first":"second")}' file
```

and the result:

```
$ wc -l first second
 19 first
 81 second
100 total
```

[From GNU awk documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html): **Caution:** *In most awk implementations, including gawk,* rand() *starts generating numbers from the same starting number, or seed, each time you run awk - -  if you want a program to do different things each time it is used, you must change the seed to a value that is different in each run. To do this, use* srand(). Ie. you might want to add `BEGIN{srand()}` to the script.

**Edit:** To gather it all to one script:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    srand()                                # change the random seed 
}
NR==1 {
    print > "first"; print > "second"      # write the header to both files
    next                                   # skip to next record
}
{
    print > (rand()<=0.2?"first":"second") # print about every fifth record to first file
}' file
```

Comment: Seems like what I was looking for, but I also need to include the header row in both output files.

Comment: Add this: `NR==1{print > "first"; print > "second"; next}` before the other `print` block. It prints the first record to both of the files and skips to process the next record,

Comment: Ran the full script, but the total amount of rows increased by 2 from 519,223 to 519,225. I would have expected to only get one additional line due to the header row being duplicated.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Does either of the files have 2 headers? Also, are you sure there is a newline after the last line in the original file?

Comment: "second" actually has 2 headers. Is that a problem with the algorithm or is my data dirty?

Comment: That `next` should handle the header from duplicating. If you have it on the same line as the previous `print`, there needs to be a `; ` between them, ie. `... print "second" ; next ...` Otherwise it could be considered an empty variable and that could case the problem.

Comment: **Note** , this does actually writing sorted lines to random (two) files. If the input is already sorted, the result files are still sorted. They are **NOT** randomly distributed.

Comment: @JamesBrown that did the trick, I used the `awk` command in a single line, resulting in double-header.

Comment: @Kent I might have not worded my question perfectly. I don't mind the resulting subsets being ordered as well. I just wanted lines from the input to be split into the output files randomly.

Comment: this will make the files approximately 1:4 in size, not exactly 100 vs 400.

Comment: It could also put ALL of the input file into one file and leave the other empty since rand() could return a number less than 0.2 on every invocation. I wouldn't use rand() in this way for this task if you really do need to get close to 400 in one and 100 in another - instead just `shuf` the input and put the first 400 lines it outputs in 1 file and the rest in another and then you're guaranteed a 400/100 split.

Answer (score 2):

```
split -l 400000 <(shuf file.csv)
```

hope that this will give you a hand.

Comment: Neither of the split files retained the header row of my original file, guessing it was also shuffled. Can I somehow exclude it and then later add it to the new files?

Comment: @AlexH you can cut the header line before shuf and split. later on add the headers to split files.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file.csv
header
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ awk 'NR==1{print > "big"; print > "small"; next} 1' file.csv |
shuf |
awk '{print >> (NR<=7 ? "big" : "small")}'

$ cat big
header
10
5
9
2
8
1
3

$ cat small
header
4
6
7
```

Just change `7` to `400000`. The above assumes you don't need the order of lines in the output to be the same as their order in the input. If you do care about the output order then it's a small tweak:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{print NR,$0 > "big"; print NR,$0 > "small"; next} {print NR,$0}' file.csv |
shuf |
awk '{print >> (NR<=7 ? "big" : "small")}'

$ sort -n big | cut -f2-
header
1
4
5
6
8
9
10

$ sort -n small | cut -f2-
header
2
3
7
```